# Nacl_IO block thread until fopen is done

Tags: multithreading, posix, google-nativeclient

I am writing a screen recorder using NaCl, inside a thread I want to open a file. the file takes some time to open. I want to block fopen until it is done then move to the next line of code. I tried to use `pp::BlockUntilComplete()` but it did not work out. what would be the solution to make sure that fopen is done before moving forward?

I tried the same code after sometime (until the thread is over, it worked)

```
Calling thread
  video_track_.GetFrame(m_callback_factory.NewCallbackWithOutput(
      &EncoderInstance::OnGetFrame));



Called function

void EncoderInstance::OnGetFrame(
    int32_t result, pp::VideoFrame frame) {
  if (result != PP_OK)
    return;



    outfile = fopen("/persistent/cuc_ieschool.ivf", "wb");
if(outfile==NULL){
    PostMessage("Can not open output file\n");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't block on the main thread. Have you tried setting up another thread and message loop, and making the blocking call there?

Comment: I created a new thread but I could not figure out how to block the call, even this call is inside a thread. I just don't know how to block the call